# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

As a consequence of [this Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649523/integrate-int-infty-infty-xe-alpha-x2-beta-xdx), I need some help evaluating the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}dx$$

Integration by parts wouldn't simplify things and I guess that a subtle manipulation on the integrand is needed.

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: You should use the same argument combined with integration by parts. Check out this pdf as an example:
http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/h-moment.pdf
or google "integration by parts".

Comment: I'm preparing an answer in the case with $x^3$ in front of the exponential function. Will post tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Subtle? No, rather, already explained to you à propos your previous question... Do you read the comments/answers on your own questions?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried the latter manipulation.

Comment: So, for example, you did read my comment suggesting to consider the derivative with respect to beta, you pondered it in depth, you marvelled at the simplicity of the argument (like me, when I was first exposed to it), but the idea to differentiate with respect to alpha did not arise? It is a pity that none of these thoughts appear in your questions.

Comment: @UdiBehar: I gave you an answer and I referred to another?  So you can choose what answer you want to take!! By the way your question is very clear!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with evaluating the integral

$$I=-\int_{R} e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}  dx $$

Which is [Gausian type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)  then differentiate the answer with respect to alpha.

**Note:** you can use the new formula I derived a while ago which handles a more general integral than yours. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794070/integral-of-exponential-using-error-function/794100?sfb=2#794100).

Comment: So $\frac{d}{d \alpha} (I)=-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{ \alpha }\right)^{5/2} e^{\frac{\beta^2}{4  \alpha }} \left(\beta^2+2  \alpha \right)$.

Comment: Just make sure of your derivations.

Comment: See what I added.

Comment: See @Did's comments re switching the order of integration and differentiation over a noncompact interval.

Comment: @Ron Gordon : the main thing has been done!  Me myself I know what you and others hers talking about and you will find it in many of my answers!  The OP can follow what you are talking about if he is interested!!

Comment: @UdiBehar: Do not worry about the down vote? My answer solves the problem in A slick way yet I referred you to another answer! By the way the issue was raised in the comments is classical and it is not the main idea and you can find it in any advanced calculus book!! By the way do you consider accepting answers?

Answer (score 0):

$$-\alpha x^2+\beta x=-\alpha\left(x^2-\frac\beta\alpha x\right)=-\alpha\left(x-\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2+\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\implies$$

$$I(\alpha):=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-\alpha\left(x-\frac\beta{2\alpha}\right)^2}e^{\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\;dx=e^{\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\sqrt{\frac\pi{\alpha}}\implies$$

$$\implies I'(\alpha)=\sqrt\pi\; e^{\beta^2/4\alpha}\left(-\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha^{5/2}}-\frac1{2\alpha^{3/2}}\right)=-\sqrt\pi\;e^{b^2/4\alpha}\frac{\beta^2+2\alpha}{4\alpha^{5/2}}$$

But also

$$\frac d{d\alpha}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}dx=-\int_{\Bbb R}x^2e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}dx$$

because differentiation under the integral sign is allowed here since

$$f(x,\alpha):=e^{-\alpha x^2+\beta x}\;\;\text{and}\;\;f'_\alpha$$

are continuous functions everywhere in the $\;x\alpha-$plane

Comment: Continuity is not the argument that allows to differentiate under the integral sign. Please reread your lecture notes or find the theorem on WP.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I actually remembered that, but I checked and I think that's what's needed: continuity of the function and its the partial derivative. It is the theorem in page 13 here, if I didn't confused: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf , or also the theorem in page 74 of Courant's "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis", Vol. 2 .

Comment: You are applying to integrals on an unbounded interval, results valid for intervals on a compact interval. This cannot work.

Comment: @Did, I think the generalization is easy as on every bounded integral we can apply it and then pass to the limit, just as we do with improper integrals.  I remember somewhere seeing that to prove the value of the Gaussian integral for $\;e^{-x^2}\;$ . Am I wrong?

Comment: The generalization holds *under some further conditions*, these conditions hold for gaussian integrals, but all this needs to be made much clearer in your post.

Comment: @Did Thanks you, I think you're right. It seems to be that uniform convergence for the integrals on bounded intervals makes the trick but I haven't found this conveniently exposed. Do you know some source?

Comment: Uniform convergence is useless on unbounded intervals. One way or another, some *domination* condition must be checked.

Comment: Funny how this solution is getting picked apart and downvoted because it is unclear how it justified swapping the differentiation and integration operations, yet the other solution, which does the same thing without even attempting to justify anything, got upvotes and no critical comments.

Comment: @RonGordon But now it did get a critical comment, right? (Having said that, I fully agree with your remark about the upvotes there.)